# Autoscroll to a particular child in a column - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a Column widget which contain a list of widgets. And this column is inside a SingleChildScrollView. For some reasons I need to autoscroll to the third child of the column while clicking the floating button.

My code looks somewhat like this.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Column(
              children:[ getWidget1(), getWidget2(), getWidget3()],
            ),
          ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Add a key to getWidget3. And onTap of Fab do Scrollable.ensureVisible(key.currentContext!);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ScrollablePositionedList](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) instead.
Create the controller

```
  final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
```

Create scroll function

```
  void scrollTo(int index) {
    itemScrollController.scrollTo(index: index, duration: scrollDuration, curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic, alignment: 0);
  }
```

Assign it to ListBuilder

```
ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
              key: Key('builder $selected'), //attention
              itemCount: itemlength,
              itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
              itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return `yourWidgets`}
            ),
```

Call it

```
ElevatedButton(
onTap:()=> scrollTo("your index here"),
child:...)
```

Comment: I can't able to use the scrollTo method.
Error: The method 'scrollTo' isn't defined for the type 'ScrollController'.

Comment: My bad, its not defined for SingleChildScrollView. I think using ScrollablePositionedList package would be just better.

Comment: Like you told, I'm not able to pass my entire list of widgets inside item builder. It's throwing error like this
Error: The return type 'List<Widget>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.

Comment: Yeah that's because it expects widgets one by one. You can just create a list of widget and pass the index like `List myWidgetList = [getWidget1(), getWidget2(), getWidget3()];` and then `return myWidgetList[index]`

Comment: That works!!!. I have been searching this for all day along. Finally I got this.
Thanks @Emre

Comment: You're welcome my friend. Sorry it took me bit longer to form the answer than i expected

Answer (score 0):

you can see [scroll_loop_auto_scroll: ^0.0.5](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_loop_auto_scroll) may be helpful